# Azure Resource Group Template for App Services "Mobile App"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to find the correct template to use for the App Service "Mobile App" for deployment via `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

I've had a look at the template for Web App but doesn't appear to be anything to specify a type or kind for Mobile App
https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the "kind" property to a website resource, e.g.

```
       {
        "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
        "kind": "mobileapp" ...
```

Comment: Is there any requirement to add a site extension and define a new resource for `"type": "Microsoft.AppService/apiapp`. Is a Mobile App a type of apiapp or a webapp, therefore the above would suffice?

Comment: the Mobile App is just a type of webapp/site - so just add the "kind" property to a Microsoft.Web/sites resource.  (the above it sufficient).

Comment: Any idea where this is documented?  What else can go in the "kind" property?  Ideally I want to add this as an ARM parameter, so I need to know what goes in there if it **isn't** a mobile app...

Comment: It looks like "app" for a standard Web App, "functionApp" for an Azure Functions App....