# How to add Azure Mobile Service to Azure Resource Manager template?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-resource-manager

How can I add an Azure Mobile Service to an Azure Resource Manager template? I cannot find any online templates nor guidance to do this. I cannot migrate to Azure App Service just yet, and MS claims that Azure Mobile Services remain fully supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605606/azure-resource-group-template-for-app-services-mobile-app

Comment: No, Mobile App is still a preview artifact, Mobile Services is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Services are only supported in the Service Management API (ASM), not in Resource Manager.